# Generator in javascript

Tags: javascript, iterator, generator, symbols

```js
function* print() {
  yield console.log("before");
  yield console.log("hello world ");
  return console.log("this is second line ");
}

let o = print();

o.next(); //console.log("before");
o.next(); // console.log("hello world ");
o.next(); //console.log("this is second line ")
```

why iterator is accessible when I assign to o ? if I call print().next() solely , it seems that iterator will be closed after use .

Comment: "*if I call print().next() solely , it seems that iterator will be closed after use .*" no, but since you don't retain a reference to it, you don't have a way to use it. It it will be garbage collected.

Comment: `print().next()` will return a string, not an generator. `print()` will return an generator. What's the confusion you have?

Comment: When you call the generator function it will return a Generator instance. So you have to use `next` on that instance to get the value. Every time you invoke the generator function you get a new instance

Comment: @evolutionxbox it prints a tring, it yields `undefined`

Comment: .next() doesn't return the generator. Not storing the generator kinda makes it being a generator pointless.

Comment: if  o.next() is called 3 times , it will printed accordingly , but if I call print().next() 3 times it will only console.log('before').

Comment: @brianlay print() creates a new instance every time, as evidenced by the result you observed.

Comment: @brianlay if you do `arr = new Array(); arr.push(1); arr.push(2); arr.push(3);` you get an array with three values in it. But if you call `new Array().push(1); new Array().push(2); new Array().push(3);` you get three arrays with one value each. That will be garbage collected shortly because you've saved none of them. Your generator code behaves the same.

Comment: @VLAZ thx for the explanation I get it now . cheers

Answer (score 1):

From mozilla.org

> The function* declaration (function keyword followed by an asterisk) defines a generator function, which returns a Generator object.

That means, when you assign it to a variable, that variable become an object of that function. So when you call .next() for the object it iterates.

But if you directly call the print().next() function to the generator function, it does not return any object. Which looks similar to your are generating the object from scratch and calling for its first value each time.